# Trying to make a responsive navbar that hides each item

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a navbar similar to [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/) where the items shown depend on how many can fit the current width of the screen, and the rest are hidden in a drop-down menu.

Using Bootstrap, all the items in my navbar are hidden once it reaches a certain width. I've been trying to comb through the code in their website, but I'm not having much luck.

I'd like to ask for your suggestions on how I can do this.

[Here is my code so far](https://jsfiddle.net/dvgqhh4e/)

Thank you!

Edit: You know what, I'm going to make my own and not use bootstrap.

**HTML Code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <div class="inline-div">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="inline-div responsive-menu">Menu</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Directory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Food &amp; Drinks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shops &amp; Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.inline-div { display: inline-block; }
.responsive-menu { font-size: 20px; color: #000; }
.navbar {
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar { background-color: black; }
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle { border-color: black; border-radius: 0px; }
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #ffffff; background-color: #F38C1E; }
.navbar-default { background-color: white; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a { color: black; }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Bootstrap's class names the divs will have Bootstrap's JS applied to them, causing the collapse feature you're keen to avoid.  To get around this I would suggest abandoning Bootstrap's 'navbar' class system completely and styling it yourself from scratch.  You could then set up some sort of jquery to disply divs in the navbar until a certain point, at which you will display the 'hamburger' icon and hide the rest of your navbar items.  Something like this could get you started?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ViewWidth = $(window).width();
    var DivWidth = 0;
    $("li").each(function() {
        var Width = $(this).width();
        DivWidth+=Width;
        if (DivWidth > ViewWidth){
            $("#HamburgerContainer").show()
            $(this).addClass("#Collapsed");
        }
    });
});
```

This obviously still needs some work! Enough to get you started?

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar idea. I've already started creating another navbar that doesn't use bootstrap. Your solution works better than what I had in mind. My idea was checking the height of the navbar on pageload and see if it matches the "normal" height of 51px. If it's more than that, hide child li elements until it matches. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Awesome.  It's an interesting one!  Continued to play around with it at https://jsfiddle.net/dvgqhh4e/4/ and it's working a little better now.

Comment: Although I should say it's not really ideal since the JSfiddle window is a lot smaller than the view!